# How to remove unwanted ads notifications from Chrome?

Tags: notifications, chrome-for-android, malware

So I visited a torrent site (not sure if it's the cause 100% though) on my Samsung Galaxy S8 last night & since then have been getting the notifications ads from Chrome.

[image]

I downloaded & ran Malwarebytes, firewall & antivirus after the popup situation but all 3 apps say my phone is fine with nothing showing in the scan results.

How do I remove the notification ads in the Samsung Galaxy S8? Also, my Chrome browser freezes a lot now too.

Comment: clear the cache of Chrome browser, if it doesn't help both cache and data of Chrome and restart Chrome

Comment: @beeshyams How do I restart Chrome?

Comment: By swiping away from recents or restart phone

Comment: If that doesn't help see the malware tag added to question

Comment: @beeshyams Did what you said but the ads still show up once every hour at least. Why isn't MalwareBytes working to remove them?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you enabled notifications for the website `tx8t.invictioner.club`.

To turn these off, open Chrome > Site settings > Notifications. Tap `tx8t.invictioner.club`, tap the bell icon, and choose Block (if similar sites under the filter `*.invictioner.club` have notification access, block them too).

SOURCE: [Turn off notification from websites in Chrome on Android - CNET](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/turn-off-notifications-from-websites-in-chrome-on-android/)